# Foursquare Chat and Message API for iPhone

Tags: ios, foursquare

I am using Foursquare API for my application and I am able to access all nearby places , Friends and badges . Now I am looking for any message or chat API through which I can chat with foursquare Friends but not able to find that .I am thinking to create one web service for chat purpose . Is it good Idea? or please tell me if any API is there.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API for messaging or chatting with foursquare friends. You can certainly build such a web service, provided you follow the related privacy policies (https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community)